# Discord.py Rewrite Role Hierarchy Check

Tags: url-rewriting, discord, discord.py, roles

I have written a bot in discord.py rewrite. So far, it only has basic options such as !kick, !ban, and !unban. However, it is currently set up that anyone with the proper permissions can do this to anyone. This means that someone with the "Moderator" rank can ban someone with the "Admin" rank, which should not be allowed. How do I add a simple check to see if the person's rank is above/below the person they are trying to kick/ban?

Answer (score 3):

`Member` objects have a `top_role` attribute, and you can compare roles directly (higher roles are "larger"):

```
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, target: Member):
    if target.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send("You can only ban people below you")
        return
    ...
```