# Detect if a user's role is above/below a specific role (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

As the name suggests, I am wondering if my bot can detect if a user is above or below a specific role on the hierarchy. (Ex: `if ctx.author.role < 'fabled'`)

I recently saw this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510452/discord-py-rewrite-role-hierarchy-check) that responds to the author depending on the target's role.

So based on that, I wrote this line of code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
 intern = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'intern', ctx.message.guild.roles)
 if ctx.author.top_role > intern:
   print("true")
 else:
   print("false")
```

With no avail. Instead, I was returned with the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 229, in test
    if ctx.author.top_role > intern:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Role' and 'NoneType'
```

Maybe I can replace ">" with another symbol? Calling all nerds, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `role.position` to determine the position of the role. The higher the int returned the higher the position.

Using your example it would be:

```
 if ctx.author.top_role.position > intern.position:
     print("true")
 else:
     print("false")
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.position

Edit:
Sorry I just read your post again and the error is caused by your bot not being able to find the role you specified. Instead of `intern = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'intern', ctx.message.guild.roles)` try something like this, the name needs to be exact (case sensitive!):

```
intern = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Exact name of your role")
```

Or better yet, use the role ID:

```
intern = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=yourroleid)
```